# Trouble with virtualenv on Mountain Lion Developer Preview 2

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, osx-mountain-lion

So I've just updated to Mountain Lion Developer Preview 2, and suddenly my python development environment is pretty much shot. When trying to create a new virtualenv, I'm getting the following:

```
jcroft@MacBook-Pro:~/Development/Python/_VirtualEnvs$ virtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
ERROR: The executable test/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' (should be u'/Users/jcroft/Development/Python/_VirtualEnvs/test')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Any clues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your previous python version was different than the one being included in Mountain Lion, then you would most likely need to rebuild your python packages again. Did you try reinstalling virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my virtualenvs and reinstalled python via homebrew, and then did a sudo pip install virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to add `/usr/local/share/python` to your `PATH`, otherwise it will still try to use easy_install which is installed by Apple.

More info here: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python